# How to subset the values of a shiny widget based on the values of another shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app delow in which the user uploads a file. Then there is a column named `EventDate` which contains Dates. Those dates are passed to a date range Input. There is also a second widget which takes as inputs the unique values of the 1st column of the uploaded file. When the actionbutton is pressed the data frame is subseted based on the picker input.

The issue is that Im trying to subset the picker input values based on the date range so I use:

```
#dat<-subset(dat, EventDate>=input$dateRange[1]&EventDate<=input$dateRange[2])
```

but then everything is empty. Its like 'nothing selected'. How can I subset the picker Input values based on the date range input?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),
    uiOutput("dr"),
    uiOutput("picker"),
    actionButton("go","Go")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("dtable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dr<-renderUI({

    inFile <- input$file1
    df<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE))
    df$EventDate <-as.Date(df$EventDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range Input',
                   start = min(df$EventDate) ,end= max(df$EventDate) 
    )

  })
  filteredCSV <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  CSV <- eventReactive(input[["file1"]], {
    dat <- read.csv(input[["file1"]]$datapath, header = TRUE)
    dat<-data.frame(subset(dat, as.Date(EventDate)>=as.Date(input$dateRange[1], "%Y-%m-%d") & 
                         as.Date(EventDate)<=as.Date(input$dateRange[2], "%Y-%m-%d")))

    filteredCSV(dat)
    dat
  })


  output[["picker"]] <- renderUI({
    req(CSV())
    choices <- unique(as.character(CSV()[,1]))
    pickerInput("select", "Select ID", 
                choices = choices, 
                multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                selected = choices)
  })

  observeEvent(input[["go"]], {
    req(CSV())
    filteredCSV(CSV()[CSV()[,1] %in% input[["select"]],])
  })

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    req(filteredCSV())
    datatable(
      filteredCSV(), 
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = 5)      
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The `#` is the comment character in R, so in your code sample above you have commented out the `subset()` call. It would also be useful to have a sample of the data in the CSV file you will be using.

Comment: I commented it out on purpose in order to make clear the functionality without the error