# How to subset uloaded file via date range in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which the user uploads a file and the date range is passed to the `dateRangeInput()`. Then based on the date range selection a second subset is happening and passes the unique values of the 4th column of the uploaded dataset to the `pickerInput()`. But when I try to do this the pickerInput displays a 'Nothing selected' message.

my csv looks like:

```
A tibble: 375 x 4
   EventDate       month  week day  
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <ord>
 1 2017-01-01     1     1 Sun  
 2 2017-01-02     1     1 Mon  
 3 2017-01-03     1     1 Tue  
 4 2017-01-04     1     1 Wed  
 5 2017-01-05     1     1 Thu  
 6 2017-01-06     1     1 Fri  
 7 2017-01-07     1     1 Sat  
 8 2017-01-08     1     2 Sun  
 9 2017-01-09     1     2 Mon  
10 2017-01-10     1     2 Tue
```

## app

```
    # app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),
    uiOutput("dates"),
    uiOutput("id")

  ),
  mainPanel(
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$dates<-renderUI({

    inFile <- input$file1
    df<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE))
    df$EventDate <-as.Date(df$EventDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Date range Input',
                   start = min(df$EventDate) ,end= max(df$EventDate) 
    )

  })
  output$id<-renderUI({
    inFile <- input$file1
    df<-data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE))
    df<-data.frame(subset(df, EventDate>=as.Date(input$dateRange[1], "%Y-%m-%d")&EventDate<=as.Date(input$dateRange[2], "%Y-%m-%d")))

    pickerInput("select", "Select ID", 
                choices = as.character(unique(df[,4])), 
                multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                selected = as.character(unique(df[,4])))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `subset` of `df` inside `output$id`.

You convert `input$dateRange` with `as.Date`, but you don't convert `EventDate` from a factor.

If you change that line to this, you should be in business.

```
df<-data.frame(subset(df, as.Date(EventDate)>=as.Date(input$dateRange[1], "%Y-%m-%d") & 
                          as.Date(EventDate)<=as.Date(input$dateRange[2], "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

[image]

This was easy to find by simply adding `browser()` within that `renderUI` call and seeing that `df` had 0 rows.

Additionally, this isn't the question you asked, but I notice you read the `.csv` file twice. You might move that outside `renderUI` and instead assign it to a reactive value. Then you can `observe` it twice.

Comment: thank you but why this does not work here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501058/how-to-subset-the-values-of-a-shiny-widget-based-on-the-values-of-another-shiny?noredirect=1#comment108792428_61501058